# javascript: Passing functions

Tags: javascript

I'm learning javascript. I know we can pass a function to other functions after the function is defined. But I need help on understanding this example:

```
function map(func, array) {
  var result = [];
  forEach(array, function (element) {
    result.push(func(element));
  });
  return result;
}
```

From what I can understand, func is an argument of map. I need to provide a function as func. But in the tutorial I'm reading, it doesn't mention where this func come from, seems no need to specify this argument? Another example in the tutorial is the same:

```
 function count(test, array) {
  return reduce(function(total, element) {
    return total + (test(element) ? 1 : 0);
  }, 0, array);
}
```

This test function is equal to element === 0 ? 1 : 0 , but the tutorial doesn't say I need to write down the test function. Do I need to write this test function?

Comment: Maybe it is [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/).

Comment: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter6.html#p31aabc64

Comment: @Jenny: Updated my answer. In that tutorial, a pre-defined function is being passed to `map`. That function is `Math.round`. You can optionally create your own function to pass instead.

Comment: @Jenny In that link you *don't* need to write the `func` function yourself; the example uses `Math.round` as the function, so the example calls `Math.round` on each number in the array, and returns an array of the input numbers, rounded using `Math.round`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***EDIT:*** In the link to the tutorial you posted, the function passed is a pre-defined function `Math.round`. My example below shows creating your own function to pass.

---

The `map` example shows the implementation. You'd provide the function (and the Array) when you call `map`.

From the looks of it, the `map` pass the current item in the Array to your function, and your function should do something with it and return the result. The results your function returns are added to the new Array.

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5];
var my_func = function(item) { return item * 2; };

var new_arr = map(my_func, arr);

console.log(new_arr); // [2,4,6,8,10]
```

1. we created an Array *(`arr`)*,
2. we created a function *(`my_func`)*, which takes whatever it's given, and multiplies it by 2.
3. we passed both to `map`
4. the `map` function iterates our `arr`, passing the current item in each iteration to our function.
5. our function takes the current item, and returns the result of multiplying it by 2.
6. the `map` function takes that result, and adds it to the new Array.
7. when the iteration is done, the `map` function returns the new Array.

Comment: Thanks for helping. After reading your answer, I just figured out the equals is the function test.

Answer (score 0):

When you call map, you pass an inline function, or an existing function.

```
// The following would return [2,3,4]
map(function(item) { return item + 1}, [1,2,3]);

function double(item) {return item*2}
map(double, [1,2,3])
// returns [2,4,6]

// Your example, Math.round
map(Math.round, [0.01, 2, 9.89, Math.PI])
// returns [0,2,10,3]
```

Another way to say it is, a function can be passed to another function just like any other argument. This is on the same lines that a function is just like any other variable can be passed or returned from a function

```
function createAdder(toAdd) {
    return function (num) {
        return num + toAdd;
    }
}

var add5 = createAdder(5);
add5(2); // returns 7


var add7 = createAdder(7);
add7(-2); // returns 5
```